# Прослушать удаление моего приложения

Tags: android

Можно прослушать ивент о том, что удалили именно мое приложение, для того чтобы сделать какое-нибудь действие, например, отправить на сервер запрос, чтобы там почистить данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, посмотрите на [SO обсуждение этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-it-works-warning-that-app-is-going-to-be-uninstalled).

Сам как-то задавал.

Answer (score 0):

Чего? Приложение удаляют из-за его ненадобности пользователю. Он посмотрел, поклацал, а потом удалил. Но никак не то, что Вы предлагаете.

Просмотр удаления приложения можно посмотреть в Google Play Console -> Название приложения -> Статистика -> Удалений за день (пользователей/устройств).

**UPD 1**

И правда, [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/380056#380137) пользователя @Barmaley решит проблему лучше, чем просмотр статистики в консоле, что предложил я.